# Error Comparing with Lambda Expressions Java

Tags: java, lambda, compare

The following code does not correctly sort the arrays.

```
public void sortByQuantity() {
    Arrays.sort(sortedByQuantity, (Item i1, Item i2) -> Double.compare(i1.getQuantity(), i1.getQuantity()));
}
public void sortByPrice() {
    Arrays.sort(sortedByPrice, (Item i1, Item i2) -> Double.compare(i1.getPrice(), i2.getPrice()));
}
```

I tried using lambda expression, and although there is no console error, not sorting occurs.
Item Class:

```
public class Item {
    private String name;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;

    public void setName (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName () {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setQuantity (int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public int getQuantity () {
        return this.quantity;
    }
    public void setPrice (double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public double getPrice () {
        return this.price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you copied and pasted wrong, change this:

```
Double.compare(i1.getQuantity(), i1.getQuantity())
```

To this:

```
Double.compare(i1.getQuantity(), i2.getQuantity())
```